# Creating a Cron Job - Linux / Python

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu

Hi I have a Django script that I need to run,

I think the commands could be called through bash.

Thing is the script causes memory leaks after a long a period of time, so I would like to create an external cron job which calls the Python script. So the script would terminate and restart while retaking the lost memory.

---

Can someone point me in the right direction? I know quite little on the subject, and feel a bit lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an executable, say `/home/bin/foobar`, that restarts the script, and want to run it (say) every 10 minutes, the crontab entry needs to be:

```
*/10 * * * *  /home/bin/foobar
```

which says to run it at every minute divisible by 10, every hour, every day.

If you save this (and any other periodic jobs you want to run) as, say, `/home/bin/mycrontab`, then just do `crontab /home/bin/crontab` and the system will do the rest (the script runs with your userid).

To see what periodic jobs you have already scheduled under the current userid, if any, do `crontab -l`.

Comment: @Alex Ciao! Grazie per la risposta! In case you are not italian and I made a fool out of myself... then thanks for you answer. :) I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @RadiantHex, italiano vero (anche se vivo a Palo Alto, CA, la crema da barba alla menta [[ProRaso]] non mi manca;-).

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [custom management commands](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) for your django app?  They work like any other command from `manage.py`, except you can write them.

> Applications can register their own
>   actions with manage.py. For example,
>   you might want to add a manage.py
>   action for a Django app that you’re
>   distributing.
>
> To do this, just add a
>   management/commands directory to your
>   application. Each Python module in
>   that directory will be auto-discovered
>   and registered as a command that can
>   be executed as an action when you run
>   manage.py.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a cron job is that it will start every so often regardless of whether the previous instance is finished. What I would recommend is to have your script start a new instance of itself after a certain amount of time, then exit.

Answer (score 1):

i think http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/ should be interesting for you

its a platform independand cron-lib for django, and works as well on windows servers