# How do I know if jobs have been/are performing? - Crontab

Tags: python, linux, django, cron

I have followed the suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339725/creating-a-cron-job-linux-python)

as I am using Django, I have set the script to store date and time of each run of the script in the db, but no entry has been stored yet in the database.

---

Is there a way to figure out, other than typing "top" and searching through?

Comment: Does your job write a log file?  If not why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would probably configure cron to mail yourself any output by using `MAILTO`:

In /etc/crontab:

```
MAILTO=username
```

Second, I usually add something to my script that (almost) cannot possibly fail, like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0 ran on `date +%c`" >> /tmp/crontab_test.log

# ... rest of program
```

If you're calling a python script directly from cron, you could do something similar or create a wrapper shell script.

Comment: @Kaleb thank you very much indeed! I have edited /etc/crontab, and added MAILTO=username@gmail.com. No emails yet, I think the script fails half way through.

Comment: Make sure you run `newaliases` as alfredodeza pointed out. I've never tried to send it to anything but a local user account, so I'm not positive you can. The docs say it's "sent to the user so named."

Comment: also, make sure it's not being picked up by the spam filter

Comment: If it wasn't clear, you'll only get an e-mail if the program outputs something to standard output (and likely standard error). A simple echo program should cause an e-mail to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

If you have sendmail installed, you can add the following to '/etc/aliases'

root:  your_name@domain.com

After you do that, update the aliases running this command:

```
sudo newaliases
```

Cron will automatically email you every time a job is run. No need to specify that in the crontab file.

Also, make sure you *test* your email capabilities (e.g. make sure you are able to send emails from the server) and lastly, create a trivial cronjob and test if you receive an email.

Do not assume!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting up cron to send email, you can send the output of cron to a seperate syslog log facility by adding the following to your `/etc/syslog.conf`.

```
# Log cron stuff 
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron.log
```

This should log a message to /var/log/cron.log each time a job is run.

Comment: I have no syslog.conf! I'm using Ubuntu 9... I'll see if I can find something thank btw!

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala), the sysklogd package has been replaced with rsyslog.  According to the release notes, configurations in /etc/syslog.conf will be automatically converted to /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.  http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes/910