# running a python script with cron

Tags: python, cron

It might be very simple question, but how could I run a python script on my fedora dist every 2 days?

Thanks

Antonis

Comment: What part of cron confuses you?  Creating the schedule?  Or running a Python script?  What part of the cron man pages have you read? What have you tried?  What errors are you getting? Can you be more specific on what help you need?

Comment: S.Lott, I think he wanted a quick solution. Not sure, if these kind of questions should be encouraged.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I just needed a quick solution. I know should read the man pages and try different things. You are right

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Cron Job - Linux / Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339725/creating-a-cron-job-linux-python)

Comment: @S.Lott to his problem, - 'How to do this task' kind?

Comment: Thanks again both of you (the Cron schedule syntax)!

Comment: @Antonis: If you wanted the cron schedule syntax, please **update** your question so that others can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is a question on cron.
First is add a SHEBANG line on top of your python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make your script executable with `chmod +x`

And do a crontab -e and add `0 0 */2 * * /path/to/your/pythonscript.py`

Comment: +w is writable, you probably meant +x. And pretty sure you should set a minute and hour. 0 0 for example.

Comment: Thanks for correcting those plundra. +w was typo and while most often I myself make the mistake of cron editing only to realize it soon and change it quickly.