# automatic periodic execution of python script

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I have a python script that checks the info about all the host in the network.I want to automatically run the script periodically to collect data after each hour.
How can i run the python script automatically after each hour in linux(ubuntu)
I am trying adding the command in crontab but it is not performing the operation.

Comment: Cron is the normal way to do this. Since your problem is with scheduling and not with Python I suggest to repost to serverfault with a detailed description of how you configured cron and what went wrong.

Comment: @user2552950 : Please visit the below link: 
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460262/running-a-python-script-with-cron)
Hope it will help you.

Comment: "but it is not performing the operation." You probably forgot to set a PATH or PYTHONPATH, didn't make the script executable or the script doesn't have a Python she-bang.